# Compartilhar link no Instagram

Tags: php, integração, instagram-api

Tem como compartilhar link no Instagram com a mesma facilidade com que faço no WhatsApp pelo meu site?

**Exemplo:**

> whatsapp://send?text=http://

Há algo simplificado assim para o Instagram?

Comment: Não há como compartilhar link no Instagram, somente imagens, para começar. A única forma de "compartilhar" é utilizando o Andoid Intents e/ou o iPhone Hook, mas que exige muito mais do que somente um link. Tem informações sobre isso aqui: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/.

Comment: Você quer php ou por protocolo?

Comment: Aparentemente o Instagram não tem uma API para isso ainda.